# Рассчитать сумму значений HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Подскажите пожалуйста, следующий момент.

Есть хэш – таблица вида `HashMap<Integer, List<Objects>>`

Ключи — это порядковый номер кабинета с 1. Всего кабинетов 5.

В значениях `List<Objects>` хранятся значения двух типов String и Integer. ФИО сотрудника (String fullName) и размер заработной платы (Integer salary) соответственно.

Пример:

```
    Иванов Иван Иванович 50000
    Петров Павел Павлович 38000
    Семенов Семен Семенович 58000
```

Не могу понять, как получить сумму зарплат сотрудников по кабинетам.

Есть идея, что нужно в методе по получению суммы зарплат, который получается должен в качестве аргумента принимать основную мапу, создать новый `HashMap<Integer, Integer>` и заполнять его из `List<Objects>` основной мапы суммами зарплат по кабинету в качестве значений и номерами кабинетов в качестве ключей циклом `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)`, каждую итерацию записывая данные в новую мапу метода. А уж потом с этой хэш - таблицей работать по желанию.
Вижу решение так, но не могу понять именно реализацию непосредственно по коду.

**Дополнение:**

Решаю небольшую разновидность задачи, со считыванием данных в которой [Дмитрий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/269255/%D0%94%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9) мне очень помог ранее.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1399756/491343

Метод psmv в его примере я заменил на нестатический метод.

Также в этом классе создал `HashMap<Integer, List<Objects>> totalStats`, который инициализируется в конструкторе класса. В классе Main у меня метод psvm, в котором меню с выбором действий, в том числе считывание данных и планируемое их сравнение и т.д..

В цикле по списку `filesList` убрал печать и добавил метод `totalStats.put(K key, V value)`, который используя информацию из названия пути файла с нужным индексом в качестве ключа пока не закончатся файлы, заполняет `HashMap<1, List<Objects>>` , `HashMap<2, List<Objects>>`   и т.д..

`List<Objects>` как раз и получается после парсинга csv через вспомогательный класс.

```
class Objects {


    private final String fullName;
    private final Integer salary;

    public Objects(String[] columns) {
        this.fullName = columns[0];
        this.salary = Integer.valueOf(columns[1]);
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }


    public Integer getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

}
```

Считывание работает, судя по дебагу мапы, информация успешно заносится по ключам и значениям, во всяком случае на мой взгляд зелёного новичка.

И вот не могу понять, как найти сумму зарплат из первого кабинета, из второго кабинета и т.д., чтобы они также хранилась в отдельной HashMap и на время работы программы я мог получать эти значения по ключу (номеру кабинета).

Количество кабинетов может быть разное, но на момент анализа данных парсинг уже должен быть сделан (потом сделаю проверку основой мапы методом `hashMap.isEmpty()`, это не проблема), поэтому, как я думаю, количество итераций при заполнении циклом новой мапы с суммами зарплат по кабинетам `HashMap<Integer, Integer> sumSalaryOffices` должно быть в диапазоне от `i = 0` до `i < totalStats.size()`.

Не получается разобраться как реализовать это, т.е. как работать с переменными `List<Objects>`, чтобы, получить суммы интересующих меня переменных (геттер getSalary в классе Objects есть) и сохранить их в `HashMap<Integer, Integer> sumSalaryOffices`.

Проще говоря, если, например, для `HashMap<Integer, List<Objects>> totalStats` воспользоваться методом `totalStats.get(1)`; я получу `List<Objects>` для первого кабинета, уже разбитым по переменным благодаря классу `Objects`. Во всяком случае при дебаге в IDEA выглядит всё неплохо.

Далее мне нужно сложить все значения Integer salary по данному кабинету, занести их в `HashMap sumSalaryOffices` методом `sumSalaryOffices.put(1, 146000)`. И так пройтись по всем имеющимся кабинетам.

А потом уже работать с данной мапой (sumSalaryOffices) как мне вздумается.

Comment: подскажите, а как вы пришли к необходимости создать List<Objects> и затолкать туда все подряд?

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, класс Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача сводится к итерации по спискам-значениям внутри хэш-таблицы, то есть, к использованию вложенного цикла:
0) Создать результирующую хэш-таблицу для хранения сумм

1. Внешний цикл -- по парам "ключ-значение" внутри хэш-таблицы, которые представлены в виде `Map.Entry<Integer, List<Objects>>` и могут быть получены  при помощи метода [`Map::entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--)
2. Внутренний цикл -- расчёт суммы зарплат и запись в результат как показано ниже.

В представленном коде для расчёта/записи суммы в результат используется метод [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

```java
public static Map<Integer, Integer> countTotalSalary(Map<Integer, List<Objects>> input) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Objects>> entry : input) {
        for (Objects personSalary : entry.getValue()) {
            result.merge(entry.getKey(), personSalary.getSalary(), Integer::sum);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Аналогичный код с использованием Stream API:

```java
public static Map<Integer, Integer> countTotalSalary(Map<Integer, List<Objects>> input) {
    return input.entrySet().stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, List<Objects>>>
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            e -> e.getValue().stream() // Stream<Objects>
                .map(Objects::getSalary) // Stream<Integer>
                .reduce(0, Integer::sum) // Integer
        ));
}
```

---

Оба вышеприведённых примера кода используют функциональные методы / потоки, появившиеся в Java 8.  Более простой пример:

```java
public static Map<Integer, Integer> countTotalSalary(Map<Integer, List<Objects>> input) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Objects>> entry : input) {
        int total = 0;
        for (Objects personSalary : entry.getValue()) {
            total += personSalary.getSalary();
        }
        result.put(entry.getKey(), total);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам за помощь!